# Solving an inverse spectral problem

Tags: spectral-theory

In order to solve the inverse spectral problem:

$$ -y''(x)+q(x)y(x)= \lambda _{n}y(x) $$

If we want to obtain $ q(x) $ what we should need about the spectrum?

a) The eigenvalue staircase $ N(\lambda)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H( \lambda - \lambda _{n}) $

b) The fucntion $ E(t)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-t \lambda _{n}} $

c) The function $ C(t)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}cos(t \sqrt{\lambda}_{n}) $

d) The function $ \Delta (\lambda)= \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(1- \frac{\lambda}{\lambda _{n}}) $

If I know any of these functions, could i recover the potential $ q(x) $ ?

Boundary conditions on the half line $ [0,\infty ) $ of the form $ y(0)+by'(0)=0$ or similar.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: In unbounded intervals the spectrum is not discrete in general.

Comment: assume all the spectrum is discrete for example the potential $ V (x) \to \infty $ whenever $ |x| \to \infty$

Comment: Anyway, knowledge of each of your conditions is equivalent to to knowledge of the spectrum. But Gelfand-Levitan theorem implies that this is not enough to recover $q(x)$.

Comment: then appart from my functions a)-d) what else would i need ? thanks